# a php error was encountered in grocery_crud

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, grocery-crud

I'm trying to install `groceryCRUD`. I've already successfully installed code igniter but when I try to access `/index.php/examples` are displayed many errors such as:

```
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined property: stdClass::$</p>
<p>Filename: libraries/Grocery_CRUD.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 1612</p>

</div><div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined property: stdClass::$</p>
<p>Filename: libraries/Grocery_CRUD.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 1613</p>

</div><div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined property: stdClass::$</p>
<p>Filename: libraries/Grocery_CRUD.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 1614</p>

</div><div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined property: stdClass::$</p>
<p>Filename: libraries/Grocery_CRUD.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 1615</p>
```

this line number error code:

```
foreach($data->list as $num_row => $row)
{
    $data->list[$num_row]->primary_key_value = $row->{$data->primary_key};
    $data->list[$num_row]->edit_url = $data->edit_url.'/'.$row->{$data->primary_key};
    $data->list[$num_row]->delete_url = $data->delete_url.'/'.$row->{$data->primary_key};
    $data->list[$num_row]->read_url = $data->read_url.'/'.$row->{$data->primary_key};
}
```

Can someone please help me fixing bugs? thank you.

Comment: These errors seem like you're trying to access the data incorrectly (array vs object) or the data is not being set correctly. Comment out the four lines causing the error and try logging or print the individual variables until you can identify which one(s) are causing the errors. I would start by testing these three: `$data->list[$num_row]` `$data->primary_key` `$row->{$data->primary_key}`

Comment: this output print_r($data->list[$num_row]) : stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 1
    [departement] => Purchasing
    [tgl_daftar] => 01/06/2020
    [jabatan_id] => 2
    [aktif] => Y. if print_r($data->list[$num_row]->primary_key_value). this output : <h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined property: stdClass::$primary_key_value</p>
<p>Filename: libraries/Grocery_CRUD.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 1612</p>

Comment: Please do not add clarifications as comments. Edit them into your Question instead.